# Jordan canonical form upper diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the Jordan form of square matrix $A  \longrightarrow T^{-1}AT = J$,   $J$ needs to be upper bidiagonal; **but** should the upper diagonal be restricted to ones?.

The equations  $Av_i = v_{i-1} + \lambda_iv_i $, where $v_i$ are the columns of $T$, result from the Jordan form and they establish the linear independence of $T$'s columns. Why cant we have $Av_i = 2v_{i-1} + \lambda_iv_i $ with upper diagonal being 2 or just any number.

Comment: Because that's not what the Jordan **canonical** form is. Are you asking whether such a matrix would be as simple to analyze as the Jordan form? Close, though if you look at the formulas for *powers* of the Jordan form you will see that the blocks have a very nice form, as do square roots and other matrices of interest. It's not clear that such would be the case with such a variant.

Comment: Ones and zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Upper diagonal does not *have* to be with $1$s, it just happens to be a multiplicative unit and also the world's favorite nonzero number. If you find the Jordan form of $A/2$ and multiply the result by $2$, you'll get a matrix with $2$ instead of $1$ in the upper diagonal, as you wanted. This works with any nonzero number too.

The logic of having $1$ above the diagonal is that they form the [shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), which is the simplest (and also world's favorite) non-normal operator. If $A$ is normal, there is nothing above the diagonal in the Jordan form; otherwise it has some amount of shift going on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sometimes it is useful to look at "pseudo"-Jordan forms where instead of $1$s, you have some fixed real number $r$ in the same places. It's an easy exercise that after getting it into Jordan canonical form, there's another basis change (depending on $r$) you can do to get it into such a form.

In particular, it is useful to look at $r \to 0$. See for example, chapter 22 of V. I. Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations.